# Проблема при парсинге страницы с кириллицей

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Пытаюсь сделать разбор html-страницы русскоязычного сайта. Так вот BeautifulSoup отказывается поддерживать кириллицу. Я написал это, но не помогло. Версия BeautifulSoup 3.

```
c=urllib2.urlopen(page)
soup=BeautifulSoup(c.read(), fromEncoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: А на сайте точно utf-8 ?

Comment: mikillskegg, дело в том, что я делаю поискового робота, и сайты разные. Поэтому как можно поступить в данной ситуации?

Comment: наверное, нужно определять кодировку страниц.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Надо как минимум читать заголовок полученной старницы, а именно:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте указывать парсер и кодировку:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(c.read(), 'html.parser', from_encoding='windows-1251')
```